# Select all rows that either have attribute satisfy criteria or not set

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table:

```
id num attr
------------
1  A   x
2  A   y
3  B   x
4  C   y
```

This query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE attr = y` returns everything that has `attr` set to y and excludes everything else in results:

```
2  A   y
4  C   y
```

I need a lists of all unique `num` values in the table (including those that have attr = y and those that don't have it), and `attr` values. For example:

```
2  A   y
3  B   
4  C   y
```

Is it possible and how?

Comment: Select Distinct on the 'num' column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, num, IF(attr='y',attr,'') as attr
FROM table
GROUP BY num
```

try this:

```
SELECT id, num, IF(FIND_IN_SET('y', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT attr))>0, 'y', '') as attr
FROM table
GROUP BY num
```

but this will work good if attr column is not resource consuming (integers, chars or small varchars).
Overwise it might be not resource consuming, and may be it would worth to put subqueries in

---

I will explain this one.

First (actually last :) ) and main thing - the query has `GROUP BY` .
Having `GROUP BY` allows to use `GROUP_CONCAT()`. This function with `DISTINCT` creates comma separated list of distinct values of a column. So, in your case `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT attr)` will return something like this:

```
id num attr
------------
1  A   x,y
3  B   x
4  C   y
```

`FIND_IN_SET()` searches for given value within comma separated list. It returns position of searched-for element within the list.
So in this case it will be:

```
id num attr FIND_IN_SET('y',GROUP_CONCAT.....)
----------------------
1  A   x,y 2
3  B   x   0
4  C   y   1
```

And last statement: `IF()` - if `FIND_IN_SET()` returns any value greater than 0 - means there is a records with 'y'

Hope this clears the query.

---

One with subqueries looks even more resources consuming...

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE attr='y')
AND num NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT num FROM table WHERE attr='y')
```

Comment: Sounds logical, but result had A's and B's attr empty. Only 'C' had 'attr' showing as 'y'.

Comment: Thanks, @cyadvert. The new query works great! And solves my current problem. Although very complicated for my understanding :) I was trying to solve the problem with subqueries initially without success. Any chance of helping out with subqueries for the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: What a great explanation! Thanks for your input @cyadvert. The subqueries version worked too but with `OR` instead of `AND` in my case like this: `SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE attr='y')
OR num NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT num FROM table1 WHERE attr='y')`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `DISTINCT` keyword to select different values from the column.

Your query should be like

```
SELECT DISTINCT num,id,attr
FROM table
WHERE where_conditions
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Invalid comma before DISTINCT. But anyway it returns same result as by original query, missing 'B'.